# jenkins+espresso

Tags: jenkins, espresso

Написал Espresso тесты на Android проект. Все тесты проходят на текущий момент. Требуется запустить их на jenkins. На jenkins создал сборку приложения и тестов, запустил тесты и вижу

> PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 299, 749 and precision: 16, 16' on view '(with id: *********:id/authorization_sign_in_btn and is displayed on the screen to the user).

Это значит, что не может нажать на кнопку, но ведь на локали все норм! В чем может быть дело? Судя по скриншотам, тоже все норм, кнопка, по которой пытается нажать есть и вся видна на экране.

Answer (score 0):

В этом и есть собственно сложность тестов, так как запуская их по отдельности,  вы проверяете только один тест. Наверняка у Вас есть 'конфликтные'  тесты, которые между собой пересекаются. Поэтому стоит изолировать каждый тест друг от друга. Как вариант перед стартом нового теста чистить бд в `@Before`.